Clone HDD with Windows XP to SSD
I need some help with a problem I’m trying to solve for my dad’s workshop.
He has a computer  responsible of a aligner machine. This machine is as old as the mentioned computer. The machine works fine, and changing it will mean spending multiple thousands.
What happens with the computer is it’s so slow that sometimes it freezes and don’t start the OS correctly.
My first thought was building a brand new computer, installing a modern OS and asking the machine provider for the software needed. When asked, the provider tells me that he must send me the computer from its factory with some things already installed. This budget is again too much money just for upgrading a computer.
Then I thought about cloning the existing software into a new SSD. I did this with clonezilla copying byte per byte into a 512gb SSD. That process ended well, but when I try to boot this cloned OS in a modern computer it only appears an underscore blinking in an infinite loop.
Any thoughts about all of this? Was the method wrong? May the hardware be too modern?
Thank you in advance :)

It might be the other way around - XP might need some settings, and possibly hardware support the modern machine has. Does the SSD boot in the old machine?

Controllers are often relatively specialized computers, and the software running on them tends to be written in ways not commonly used elsewhere. Cloning a very old computer to new hardware will not work: there have been too many changes and you would have to get very, VERY lucky in order for the system to function at even a very basic level, let along communicate correctly with the machine. When I worked IT in a machine shop, we kept copies of the hard drives for the oldest machine's systems, and so when there was a problem with one we'd just swap a drive in with a working copy of the system.

Did you check the BIOS to see if any options to turn "secure boot" or UEFI off?  Find some kind of legacy mode.  The other major issue is the IDE controller, if your BIOS allows you to turn OFF AHCI,RAID, and etc do that.  Maybe before cloning it again, you should switch the XP unit from whatever the store controller is to the generic standard mode.  The other issue is most new hardware won't have chipset/controller drivers for XP.  In order to avoid this quagmire of issues converting it to a VM makes a lot more sense.

2 suggestions,
1: find the formfactor of the current laptop's harddrive, clone it into a SSD of the same formfactor, and replace the harddrive with the SSD. The massive IO upgrade (likely going from a few kb/s random IO to 300+MB/s random IO) Should give a significant speedup of the old laptop.
2: use the Starwind P2V converter to make a virtual machine image of the old laptop, then boot it up on your modern computer using something like VirtualBox or VMWare Workstation. (with VMWare having vastly superior graphics performance, fwiw. Games that run with 1FPS or just crash in VirtualBox can easily run 30+ FPS on VMWare.)
Here is a picture of how that would look:


Then I thought about cloning the existing software into a new SSD. I did this with clonezilla copying byte per byte into a 512gb SSD. That process ended well, but when I try to boot this cloned OS in a modern computer it only appears an underscore blinking in an infinite loop.

Yeah you cloned a OS configured to booting from BIOS/IDE and tried booting it on a computer booting on UEFI/AHCI.  Some laptops can be changed to boot BIOS/IDE, but that is rare. Expensive Lenovo ThinkPads can still be configured to do this, I believe. At least my 2022 $2000 Lenovo ThinkPad P73 can be configured to boot in BIOS/IDE mode, but most modern laptops cannot.

You can even find instructions for install Windows XP on a virtual machine, e.g., https://eprebys.faculty.ucdavis.edu/2020/04/08/installing-windows-xp-in-virtualbox-or-other-vm/ . Then transfer software. However, does the new PC have the physical ports (e.g., RS-232, RS-485, or parallel port)? If not, adapters are needed.

The old operating system probably won't work with the new hardware. You could try enabling legacy mode in the BIOS or consider using a virtual machine. Another option is to use an older computer that is more similar in age to the aligner.
